# converting parquet files in S3 to CSV and store back in S3

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, parquet, amazon-athena

**Information:**

I have parquet files stored in S3 which I need to convert into CSV and store back into S3.
the way I have the parquet files structured in S3 is as so:

```
2019
2020
 |- 01
 ...
 |- 12
   |- 01
   ...
   |- 29
     |- part-0000.snappy.parquet
     |- part-0001.snappy.parquet
     ...
     |- part-1000.snappy.parquet
     ...
```

**The solution required:**

- Any AWS tooling (needs to use lambda, no EC2, ECS) (open to suggestions though)
- That the CSV files keep their headers during conversion (if they are split up)
- That the CSV retain are original information and have no added columns/information
- That the converted CSV file remain around 50-100MB

**The solution I have already tried:**

***"entire folder method"***

Using Athena `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` -> `CREATE TABLE AS` on the entire data folder (e.g: s3://2020/06/01/)

fig: #1

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database.table_name (
         value_0 bigint,
         value_1 string,
         value_2 string,
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'serialization.format' = '1' )
LOCATION 's3://2020/06/01' TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false')
```

fig: #2

```sql
CREATE TABLE database.different_table_name
WITH ( format='TEXTFILE', field_delimiter=',', external_location='s3://2020/06/01-output') AS
SELECT * FROM database.table_name
```

doing this "entire folder method" works at converting parquet to CSV but leaves the CSV files at around 1GB+ size which is way too large. I tried creating a solution to split up the CSV files (thanks to help from this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/tutorials-importing-data-lambda-function-input-split.html)) but it failed since lambda has a 15-minute limit & memory constraints which made it difficult to split about all these 1GB+ CSV files into about 50-100MB files.

***"single file method"***

using the same `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` (see fig: #1) and

fig: #3

```sql
CREATE TABLE database.different_table_name
WITH ( format = 'TEXTFILE', field_delimiter=',', external_location = 's3://2020/06/01-output') AS
SELECT *, "$path" FROM database.table_name
WHERE "$path" LIKE 's3://2020/06/01/part-0000.snappy.parquet';
```

doing this "single file method" required me to integrate AWS SQS to listen to events from S3 for objects created in the bucket which looked for `.snappy.parquet`. this solution converted the parquet to CSV and created CSVs which fit the size requirements. the only issue is that the CSVs were missing headers, and had additional fields which never existed in the parquet in the first place such as the entire bucket location.

Comment: This might help: [Set the Number or Size of Files for a CTAS Query in Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/set-file-number-size-ctas-athena/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use dask

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_parquet(s3://bucket_path/*.parquet’)
#converting dask df to pandas df 
df = df.compute()
df.to_csv(’out.csv’)
```

Answer (score 0):

While there's no way to configure the output file sizes, you can control the number out files in each output partition when using CTAS in Athena. The key is to use the `bucket_count` and `bucketed_by` configuration parameters, as described here: [How can I set the number or size of files when I run a CTAS query in Athena?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/set-file-number-size-ctas-athena/). Run a few conversions and record the sizes of the Parquet and CSV files, and use that as a heuristic for how many buckets to configure for each job, each bucket will become one file.

When working with Athena from Lambda you can use [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) to avoid the need for the Lambda function to run while Athena is executing. Use the [Poll for Job Status](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-project-job-poller.html) tutorial as a starting point. It's especially useful when running CTAS jobs since these tend to take longer to run.